# keyboard layout switch without doing from DE to EN

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, and this problem occurs after updating from 13.04:

I'm starting ubuntu, the keyboard layout is set to german, what I need. But while working, it can change random to the englisch layout.

When this occurs, I must only type <kbd>Str</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to the console and then <kbd>Str</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back, and the tastatur works well as nothing has happened. What can be the problem?

(I have deactivate switching to other keyboard layouts with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

You must add the command:

```
setxkbmap de
```

in the Autostart of the User.

### Adding Autostart in Ubuntu

To open a menue for that in Ubuntu, you must type the command:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

And now you can add the command in the list

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 13.10 or Later**. This work better then setxkbmap with Gnome/Unity keyboard layout indicator.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

0 is the layout index (0 default or top layout). Layouts indexed starting from 0.

So you can create a keyboard shortcut for any layout you want using tweak tools, gnome actions, compiz actions plugin, ...